# Javascript getJSON not working (Possibly Cross Domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im getting a JSON from a server, and when I type the url into the browser, I can see the JSON data. And when I use curl to get the JSON I can also see the data. But when I try to use a html page locally to access the data i get an error. I've tried using

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

but I still get an error, is there anyway I can solve this possible cross domain problem?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSONP (JSON with padding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for crossdomain requests instead. Also see the [jquery plugin](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) for easier jsonp handling (even basic error handling). Here is a nice [example page](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/#.T_F8VbAe4eA).

Comment: Can you please give me or direct me to an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

If the server supports `JSONP`, then you could get the data by `getJSON` by appending `?callback=?` to the url.

But if the response is just json format like:

```
{a: 1, b:2}
```

then you can't use ajax to get the data directly. One solution is to make a proxy, in your server side, get the remote json data and then output it again to avoid cross domain problem.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have suggested suitable alternatives (JSONP), but to explain *why* it's not working;

The support of `cors` is not something you can just *turn on*. It's something the browser, and the server, has to support.

For more info see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but to summarise:

- The server needs to emit a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header (or tailor `*` to be the domain you wish to allow).
- You need to be using Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, Chrome 3, IE 8 or Opera 12.

You can also see the documentation for `jQuery.support.cors` on the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/).